# Existence of Unitary Map

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I've been recently introduced to Unitary operators of a Hilbert space and I've been wondering the following.

Existence of a unitary operator $T$ on a (possibly infinite) Hilbert space $H$ is simple enough. The identity map works and otherwise any "partial isometry" with full initial and final subspace does as well.

However, if I'm given subspaces $U, V \subset H$, then is there any assumption (not directly assuming that $U = V$) I can make that guarantees the existence of unitary operator $T:H\to H$ such that the restriction

$$T\restriction_U:U\to V$$

is a surjective isometry? Would I somehow be able to construct a unitary operator if I assumed $\dim U = \dim V$?

Comment: You can assign a dimension to a Hilbert space equal to the cardinality of a complete orthonormal basis. There is a unitary map between $U$ and $V$ iff the dimensions of $U$ and $V$ are the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need exactly $\dim U=\dim V$ and $\dim U^\perp=\dim V^\perp $, in the sense that they have bases with the same cardinality.

Suppose that $\{e_j\}_{j\in J}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U$ and that $\{f_j\}_{j\in J}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$.

Extend both basis to orthonormal bases of $H$, $\{e_j\}_{j\in K}$, $\{f_j\}_{j\in K}$, where $K\supset J$.

Now define $Te_j=f_j$ and extend by linearity. This map is a unitary that maps $U$ to $V$ (it's an exercise you have to do, to show that $T$ defines a bounded operator and that it is a unitary).

Comment: They also need to have equal codimension.

Comment: Yes, of course. It is exactly what my argument uses.

Comment: sorry for opening an old question.. but could someone give some hints on how to prove that  $T:U\rightarrow V$ is unitary?

Comment: More than "hints", the last paragraph in the answer says exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: I see. what's strange to me if that I can see that $T:H\rightarrow H$ is unitary, but in general restrictions of unitary operators are not..

Comment: Of course. But in this case the bases used to define $T$ have been chosen carefully. Basically, what one is doing is writing $T$ as a direct sum of two unitaries, one $U\to V$, and the other $U^\perp\to V^\perp$.

Comment: it's clear now, thanks

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: one last question. does this result work when the Hilbert space have finite dimension?

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference at all. Things are simple in that case, because the equality of the codimensions comes for free, and you don't have to extend $T$ to the closure of the span of the orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to just know that $\dim U=\dim V$.  For instance, suppose $U=H$ and $V$ is the orthogonal complement of a single nonzero vector $v\in H$.  As long as $H$ is infinite-dimensional, $U$ and $V$ will have the same dimension, but clearly no unitary $T:H\to H$ can map $U$ to $V$, since then $T$ would not be surjective.  More generally, one can see that if such a unitary exists, then one must have not only that $\dim U=\dim V$ but also that $\dim U^\perp=\dim V^\perp$.

Conversely, if $\dim U=\dim V$ and $\dim U^\perp=\dim V^\perp$, then there does exist such an isometry.  To see this, let $T_0:U\to V$ be any unitary isomorphism and let $T_1:U^\perp\to V^\perp$ be any unitary isomorphism, and let $P:H\to U$ be the orthogonal projection onto $U$.  Define $T:H\to H$ by $T(v)=T_0(Pv)+T_1(v-Pv)$.  It is straightforward to check that this is unitary, and its restriction to $U$ is $T_0$.